# Pass Ruby object's instance variables to another class's initializer as a map

Tags: ruby, symbols, instance-variables

I'm using the `xml-mapping` gem to read some XML, and I want to feed the mapping objects into the initializers for some existing domain classes. So given XML like:

```
<foo bar="baz"><qux>quux</qux></foo>
```

I get an object like:

```
#<Foo @bar="baz", @qux="quux">
```

I then want to feed it to a domain class like:

```
class MyFoo
  def initialize(bar:, qux:)
    # ... etc.
  end
end
```

(Note that in `MyFoo` the attributes are read-only, and there's some validation and transformation that goes on in the initializer, so it's not simply a matter of copying instance variables from one to the other.)

I tried transforming the instance variables to a map, thus:

```
foo.instance_variables.map { |name| [name, foo.instance_variable_get(name)] }.to_h
```

which produces:

```
{ :@bar->"baz", :@qux->"quux" }
```

This is **almost** what I need for the `MyFoo` initializer, but not quite -- what I need is

```
{ :bar->"baz", :qux->"quux" }
```

Is there a way to transform the instance variable names to symbols **without** the `@`-sign?

Alternatively, is there an easier way to say "initialize yourself from all the attributes in this object"?

Comment: you can try  `foo.instance_variables.map { |name| [name.to_s.delete('@').to_sym, foo.instance_variable_get(name)] }.to_h`

Comment: I am probably late with answer :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andrey's comment works fine, but I dislike relying on instance variables directly. I would suggest adding a custom `to_h` method to your `Foo` class. You could even tie this in with `xml-mapping` with the following:

```
class Foo
  # ...
  def self.__fields__
    @__fields__ ||= all_xml_mapping_nodes.map { |r| r.instance_variable_get(:@attrname) }
  end

  def to_h
    self.class.__fields__.each_with_object({}) do |field, acc|
      acc[field] = send(field)
    end
  end  
end
```

Then you could call `MyFoo.new(foo.to_h)`.

**EDIT**

As an extension to `XML::Mapping`:

```
module XmlMappingExtensions

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def __fields__
      @__fields__ ||= all_xml_mapping_nodes.map { |r| r.instance_variable_get(:@attrname) }
    end
  end

  def to_h
    self.class.__fields__.each_with_object({}) do |field, acc|
      acc[field] = send(field)
    end
  end  

end
```

And then either `include XmlMappingExtensions` in your `Foo` class, or:

```
module XML::Mapping
  # Note: this may break XML::Mapping if it is using this method
  # and there is probably a more graceful way to do this
  # but I just tried it and it seems to work fine...
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:include, XmlMappingExtensions)
  end
end
```

after you have loaded `XML::Mapping` and before you have loaded your `Foo` class.

Comment: I like that in principle, but I don't want to have to define those methods for every mapped class. Is there a way to add those to everything that includes `::XML::Mapping`?